# Containing information related to two models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I need to create a model to contain a set of data that is related to two separate models and is unique to that combination of those two models.

For example, lets say I have a user `Profile` model and a `Dessert` model. The `Profile` model contains the user's preferences and personal information and the `Dessert` model contains information about the dessert (calories, cost, type, etc.). I now want to create a model which will allow the user to record the results of a 'taste test' on a given dessert. Each user can perform a taste test on each dessert, but only one (that is, the taste test is unique for each user/dessert combo).

How can I achieve this? It does not seem appropriate for a `through` (as outlined here: [How do you bind a model to two other, already related models, and display the information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084596/how-do-you-bind-a-model-to-two-other-already-related-models-and-display-the-in)) because most of the time I will want to access the dessert or the user's profile without the taste test (for, say, displaying information about the dessert and comparing it to other desserts). A `through` would add a lot of unnecessary overhead.

The best solution I can come up with is create a 'TasteTest' model like so:

```
class TasteTest(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    dessert = models.ForeignKey(Dessert)
    # Taste test results here
```

I have two related questions. First, is this the best/correct way to do this? Or is there a better way? Secondly, what is the database overhead involved when doing lookups? To access the taste test for a given user on a given dessert it seems like I'll have to do something like:

```
user.profile.tastetest_set.get(dessert=given_dessert.pk)`
```

which seems like it could be an expensive lookup (though I'm really unfamiliar with DB stuff, which is why I ask).

Comment: I personally have never found sand particularly tasty. Other people might disagree though...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You've obviously never tasted a MontBlanc Sahara Selection '84 then. Erm... it's been a long day, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship with a `through` table is the right approach here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Behind the scenes, Django will create an intermediary table for a many-to-many field anyway, so worrying about extra overhead on lookups is unnecessary.  There's no way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I have a few follow up questions. If I use a `through` would there be an intermediary table (sorry, not sure if that's the right word) created for each possible user/college combination? If so that would mean a lot of new database content, particularly when there can be arbitrarily many users and 1000+ deserts. If that is the case, is that a problem for performance? Second I'm currently using a `ManyToManyField` between the profile and desert models to contain a list of favourite deserts. Should this be moved to the through?

Comment: There's one intermediate table created for the whole relationship, not one per combination.  That table will have a column for the PK of the user and a column for the PK of the dessert, plus whatever "taste test" result you have.  Performance is dependent on your database but is not usually a problem.  For the favorites question - probably, but it's not strictly required.  You can avoid some redundancy by doing so.